# What can be said about the degree of a map $f:S^{2k+1}\rightarrow S^{2k+1}$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, spheres

Let $f:S^{2k+1}\rightarrow S^{2k+1}$ be a map that factors through $\mathbb{RP}^{2k+1}$, then what can be said about the about the degree of $f$?

In the even dimensional case, we have that there exists a unique $\phi:\mathbb{RP}^{2k}\rightarrow S^{2k}$ such that $f=\phi\circ \pi$. It follows that $f_*=\phi_*\circ \pi_*$, but since the top homology of $\mathbb{RP}^{2k}$ is trivial we must have that $\pi_*=0$, so $f_*=0$ and the degree of the map must be zero.

In the odd dimensional case the top homology of $\mathbb{RP}^{2k+1}$ is $\mathbb Z$, so not much can be immediately said about the degree of $\pi$, and I am not exactly sure how to actually go about calculating the degree of $\pi$ in this case. Even if I could say something about the degree of $\pi$, I still have that $\phi_*$ is a map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, so all I could say is that the degree of $f$ is some multiple of the degree of the $\pi$ right?

I also tried looking at the cohomology rings of $\mathbb{RP}^{2k+1}$ and $S^{2k+1}$, but in both caes the ring structures essentially separates the top cohomology from the rest ring. In other words, there are no elements of lower degree that can multiply together to yield a generator of the top cohomology ring, so I don't think I can deduce anything from that...

I think my best bet is then to just calculate the degree of the $\pi_*$, but how exactly do I do that?

Comment: Yes, in the odd case, the degree of $\pi$ is $2$ (note that the antipodal map of the sphere is orientation-preserving). You can also use smooth degree theory to see immediately that the degree of $f$ is even, as the preimage of any regular value contains an even number of points.

Comment: @TedShifrin we haven't really talked about smooth degree theory in my course, how do I see that $\pi$ is orientable without appealing to the differential of $\pi$ at each point $x\in S^{2k+1}$?

Comment: No, I said the antipodal map is orientation-preserving. In your algebraic topology course, you surely have proved this to do the homology of projective space. Start by showing a single reflection across a hyperplane has degree $-1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh my bad I misread, I can see that the antipodal map is orientation preserving, but what does that tell me about the degree of the $\pi$?

Comment: Think about the image of the fundamental class under $\pi_*$, using the fact that $\pi$ is a double covering.

Answer (score 0):

From homology you can see quickly that the degree has to be even. Conversely, an even-degree map factors through a degree-2 map, which is turn factors through the projection $S^{m} \to \mathbb{R}P^{m}$ via the map $\mathbb{R}P^{m} \to S^m$ collapsing the $m-1$-skeleton.

Comment: How do you see quickly from homology that the degree has to be even?

Comment: It sends the 2-cell of the sphere to twice the 2-cell of the projective space...

Comment: Also since every map is homotopic to a cellular one, you can assume that your map _does_ collapse the $m-1$-skeleton of the projective space, so factors through the degree-2 map just like in my converse direction.